# Which way is better by clean code rules and other parameters. `switch` statement or an array of functions names

Tags: php, arrays, switch-statement

```
$action = 'action_1';
```

Which way is better for actions functions and why?

```
$actions = [
    'action_1' => 'a',
    'action_2' => 'b',
    'action_3' => 'c',
];
$action_function_name = array_key_exists($action, $actions) ? $actions[$action] : 'd';
$action_function_name();
```

OR

```
switch ($action) {
    case 'action_1':
        a();
        break;
    case 'action_2':
        b();
        break;
    case 'action_3':
        b();
        break;
    default:
        d();
}
```

OR Is there more than 2 variants to properly complete this?

Comment: If the set of methods is static (fixed), then always use normal conditionals, so `switch` for multiple cases and a simple `if/else` for exceptions. Reason is readability which is one of the most important rules to obey when coding. Arrays of methods look clean and promising at first, but they tend to make code complex and hard to read because it gets generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be overkill but what about a function container using lambdas? Depending on the complexity of your problem it could be more flexible.

```
class FunctionContainer
{
    private $functionMap = [];    
    private $default;

    public function addFunction($name, \Closure $closure)
    {
        $this->functionMap[$name] = $closure;
    }

    public function setDefault(\Closure $closure)
    {
        $this->default = $closure;
    }

    public function callFunction($name)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($name, $this->functionMap)) {
            call_user_func($this->functionMap[$name]);
        } else {
            call_user_func($this->default);
        }
    }
}
```

You could use the container like that:

```
//Setting the functions
$functionContainer->setDefault(function() {
    d();
});

$functionContainer->add('action_1', function() {
    a();
});

$functionContainer->add('action_2', function() {
    b();
});

$functionContainer->add('action_3', function() {
    c();
});

//Calling the functions    
$functionContainer->callFunction('action_1');
//will call the default
$functionContainer->callFunction('notExists');
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the first way cause it less verbose and it's good for bug to code ratios.

Furthermore this way may be better if you want to dynamicly set the function list.

And finaly your function call may be improved to :
`call_user_func($actions[$action] ?? 'd');`